# Accept http request on node-server running on android

Tags: node.js, networking, wifi, portforwarding

I have a basic node-express app running on android(with termux), i set it up with my router's port forwarding feature so that i could access it from anywhere, but when i enter my router's IP and the port in the browser it doesn't work, i get "this site can't be reached,  took to long to respond" message, maybe this is a problem with my ISP, and if so can i not enter my smartphone's IP in the browser and access the server? I'm thinking i'll have to change some permission settings in the phone? (the router config is shown in the image below)

[image]

```
import express from "express";
import { formatDate } from "./utils.js";

const app = express();

app.use((req, _, next) => {
    console.log(`${formatDate(new Date())} => IP is ${req.ip}`);
    next();
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(req.ip);
})

app.listen(3000, (err) => {
    console.log(err ? err : `listening to port ${3000}`);
})
```